# WHMCS Action Hook

Tags: php, mysql, whmcs

Here's what I have for my WHMCS Hook:

```
<?php
function hook_api_suspend($vars) {

$table = "apis_user_profiles";
$update = array("status"=>"0");
$where = array("user_id"=>"342329");
update_query($table,$update,$where);
}

add_hook('AfterModuleSuspend', 1, 'hook_api_suspend');

?>
```

This is the line I'm specifically having problems with:

```
$where = array("user_id"=>"342329");
```

When I suspend an account, it does update the status correctly for the user with a `user_id` of 342329.  However, how can I make it use the user_id of the actual user's account who is getting suspended?  I've already tried entering a few variables there but none seem to be working...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [hook documentation](http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks:AfterModuleSuspend), the user id is passed in $vars['params']['userid']. and the $where array becomes:

```
$where = array("user_id" => $vars['params']['userid']);
```